# I want to create my custom 'build.gradle' file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I want to create my custom 'build.gradle' file.

I want that, if i create a new project from android studio than studio will automatically include `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'` dependency in my `build.gradle` file.

Please help. Thanks in advance :)

How can i accomplish this?

Comment: I'm curious - are you only going make projects using Gson? Why?

Comment: studio automatically adds some dependencies in the gradle file, i only want to add `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'` this dependency along with them.

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35199899/android-studio-create-project-template-for-new-projects

Answer (score 0):

You can modify templates on Android Studio.

The path is : \plugins\android\lib\templates\

For your example, you can edit "gradle-projects\NewAndroidModule\root\build.gradle.ftl"