# Include same dependencies for every new project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Every time I start a project in Android, I have to go and grab the different `libraries/dependencies` that I usually use.

Is there a way to have these dependencies in a file/or build file that I can always `import/include` when I start a new project? I find it better than copy-paste every time
Thanks

Comment: You can create your own project template in AS: This one would appear in the New -> Project dialog Or you create a file template by your own. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35199899/android-studio-create-project-template-for-new-projects https://medium.com/@factoryhr/how-to-make-templates-in-android-studio-d83326a06463

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can apply `dependencies` blocks like this:

```
apply from: "dependencies.gradle"
```

Comment: Thank you. Interesting one. What would dependencies.gradle look like? Complete gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

your dependencies are listed in build.gradle(project root and app directory). Copy/move these existing build.gradles in your new project.