# How can I avoid adding the plugins 'kotlin-android-extensions' everytime in the build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Since I have uninstalled my Android Studio once, it cannot add the `kotlin-android-extensions` automatically. I have to add it every time I create the project.
How can I default to using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better not to use `kotlin-android-extensions` it will be depricated in [Kotlin 1.4.20](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/v1.4.20-M2/ChangeLog.md?utm_source=telegram&utm_medium=post&utm_campaign=kotlin-slyshali-o-ko#1420-m2) and after that removed.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can do is to modify the project template from Android Studio. Look at this SO post to see where it's stored and how to modify it: [Android Studio create project template for new projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35199899/android-studio-create-project-template-for-new-projects/35200693#35200693)

Comment: Thx.  I will try.

Comment: I found that Android studio delete the templates folder in new version 4.1.

Comment: it may be the reason why it cannot use the plugin automatically