# Android Studio create new project error

Tags: android

I have created many projects without any problem but today i keep getting the following error when I create a new one

```
Gradle 'MyApplication' project refresh failed
Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap
```

Any ideas about what is wrong?

Comment: Follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009717/android-studio-gradle-project-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process-initializatio). It'll solve your problem.

Answer (score 24):

You encounter following error:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough
>   space for 1572864KB object heap

This means the JVM hasn't enough memory space. 
Adding following property in the gradle.properties file will fix your problem:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Comment: CORRECT ANSWER HERE!

Comment: Firstly thank you for help. When i added this and it works org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx156m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m . But it seems i have to edit the gradle.properties file every time i create a new project cause when i create a new project it has this value org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m . Can i permanently edit the file so I don't have to edit it every singe time?

Comment: @GiannisKosmas yes is the short answer ... look into D:\Android\sdk\tools\templates ... this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24546484/how-to-create-custom-project-template-in-android-studio