# How to create new item template in Android Studio?

Tags: android, templates, android-studio

Android Studio provides a number of templates for new items - activities, fragments, services etc.

[image]

Is there a way to create a custom one? I'm using databinding extensively and I'd like to create a template, which would automatically add a viewmodel, create layout file with `layout` root item, prepare code to bind viewmodel etc.

Comment: Yes you can create it. using gradle-projects/NewAndroidModule I think this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24546484/how-to-create-custom-project-template-in-android-studio) may be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several tutorials on this. E.g., [here](https://coderwall.com/p/fsxvyw/file-templates-in-android-studio) and [here](https://riggaroo.co.za/custom-file-template-group-android-studiointellij/). The upshot is that the templates are written in [freemarker](http://freemarker.org/) template files. These have to be placed inside a sub-directory under the actual Android Studio application (e.g., on a mac it's in /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/templates/...).

Personally, I've been looking for a way to have these stored in a project-specific location (e.g., in the project repository), but have so far not found a way to do that. I think you can only make these available by placing them in that sub-directory under the application's folder.